# Insert data to collection in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

I am writing a python script which will get current latitude and longitude. The database used is MongoDB. Now, I want this obtained latitude and longitude to be saved in a particular row in the MongoDB database collection. For example, in a row which has my number. Is it possible to insert data based on this? I do not want to refer ID but other data in the row.

Did some research in Google and tried some script. Unfortunately, not working.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow @Priths ! Have a look on [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) and what is a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will even have rewards at visiting those pages. We will not write code for you. Share what you have tried so far and we will try to improve it.

Comment: Please provide us sample data in your db, and your expected input and output, and what all you have tried so far, so that we can help you better.